# Expected argument of type "biblioBundle\Entity\Profil", "integer" given

Tags: html, integer, symfony

**PersonneController.php**

```
<?php
 namespace biblioBundle\Controller;

 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

 use biblioBundle\Entity\Personne;
 use biblioBundle\Form\PersonneType;

 /**
  * Personne controller.
  *
  */
  class PersonneController extends Controller
  {
/**
 * Lists all Personne entities.
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $personnes = $em->getRepository('biblioBundle:Personne')->findAll();

    return $this->render('personne/index.html.twig', array(
        'personnes' => $personnes,
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a new Personne entity.
 *
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //$prf = $em->getRepository('biblioBundle:Profil')->findAll();

    $personne = new Personne();

    $form = $this->createForm(PersonneType::class, $personne);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($personne);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('personne_show', array('id' =>                        $personne->getIdpersonne()));

    }

    return $this->render('personne/new.html.twig', array(
        'personne' => $personne,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

**PersonneType.php**

```
<?php

namespace biblioBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use biblioBundle\Entity\Profil;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;

class PersonneType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
      * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
      * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('datenaiss', 'date')
            ->add('adresse')
            ->add('photo1')
            ->add('sexe',ChoiceType::class,array(
                 'choices' => array(
                     'H' => 'Homme',
                     'F' => 'Femme')))
            ->add('idProfil',IntegerType::class);




}

 /*   public function getName()
{
    return 'name';
}*/     

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'biblioBundle\Entity\Personne'
    ));
    }
}
```

**Personne.php**

```
<?php

namespace biblioBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

     /**
      * Personne
      *
      * @ORM\Table(name="personne", indexes= {@ORM\Index(name="FK_Appartenir2",                columns={"idProfil"})})
      * @ORM\Entity
      */
class Personne
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Nom", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Prenom", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DateNaiss", type="date", nullable=false)
 */
private $datenaiss;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Adresse", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $adresse;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Photo1", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $photo1;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Sexe", type="string", length=1, nullable=false)
 */
private $sexe;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idPersonne", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idpersonne;

/**
 * @var \biblioBundle\Entity\Profil
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="biblioBundle\Entity\Profil")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idProfil", referencedColumnName="idProfil")
 * })
 */
private $idprofil;



/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 * @return Personne
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set prenom
 *
 * @param string $prenom
 * @return Personne
 */
public function setPrenom($prenom)
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prenom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPrenom()
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

/**
 * Set datenaiss
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datenaiss
 * @return Personne
 */
public function setDatenaiss($datenaiss)
{
    $this->datenaiss = $datenaiss;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get datenaiss
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDatenaiss()
{
    return $this->datenaiss;
}

/**
 * Set adresse
 *
 * @param string $adresse
 * @return Personne
 */
public function setAdresse($adresse)
{
    $this->adresse = $adresse;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adresse
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAdresse()
{
    return $this->adresse;
}

/**
 * Set photo1
 *
 * @param string $photo1
 * @return Personne
 */
public function setPhoto1($photo1)
{
    $this->photo1 = $photo1;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photo1
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPhoto1()
{
    return $this->photo1;
}

/**
 * Set sexe
 *
 * @param string $sexe
 * @return Personne
 */
public function setSexe($sexe)
{
    $this->sexe = $sexe;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sexe
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSexe()
{
    return $this->sexe;
}

/**
 * Get idpersonne
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdpersonne()
{
    return $this->idpersonne;
}

/**
 * Set idprofil
 *
 * @param \biblioBundle\Entity\Profil $idprofil
 * @return Personne
 */
public function setIdprofil(\biblioBundle\Entity\Profil $idprofil = null)
{
    $this->idprofil = $idprofil;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idprofil
 *
 * @return \biblioBundle\Entity\Profil 
 */
public function getIdprofil()
{
    return $this->idprofil;
  }
}
```

Every time I try to run the code I get:

> {Expected argument of type "biblioBundle\Entity\Profil", "integer" given }

Please I need help.

[image: this what i get every time ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `PersonneType` class you have line:

```
->add('idProfil',IntegerType::class);
```

when in `Personne` class you have:

```
public function setIdprofil(\biblioBundle\Entity\Profil $idprofil = null)
{
    $this->idprofil = $idprofil;

    return $this;
}
```

You need to have `Profil` instance instead of integer (defined in form). How to solve this?

1. Replace `IntegerType` class to `EntityType`.
2. Add *data transformer* to form and transform `integer` to `Profil` and vice versa.
3. Replace argument $idprofil with `integer` type instead of `Profil`.